# How do I overwrite the initial entry from an array in state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, forms, state

I have a form element which allows users to submit **multiple** locations. By clicking an 'Add Location' button, it saves the values in state and allows them to submit another one. However, the first entry in `location` is always **empty**, because the initial state is kept.

I want to remove the first entry, which is always my empty initial state.

This is my state:

```
state = {
 name: "",
 location: [
           {
            addressLine1: "",
            addressLine2: "",
            country: "",
           }
          ],
 locationAdded: "",
}
```

This is what an element for one of my *location* fields looks like:

```
<Form>
  <Label>Country<Label>
    <Form.Control 
     name="country" 
     value={this.state.location.country}
     onChange={this.handleChange} />
</Form>
```

This is my `handleChange` function:

```
handleChange = event => {
   const isCheckbox = event.target.type === "checkbox";
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: isCheckbox
        ? event.target.checked
        : event.target.value
    });
  };
```

And for my 'Add Location' *button*, it has an `onClick` that calls this function:

```
onAddLocation = () => {  
         this.setState({
          location: [...this.state.location, {
            addressLine1: this.state.addressLine1,
            addressLine2: this.state.addressLine2,
            country: this.state.country,
          }],
          locationAdded: "You successfully added a location!"
        })
      };
```

Which essentially **pushes** the current `location` to my state.

This all works fine and dandy, apart from the extra empty entry. Currently in my console adding 2 locations, for example, saves it as:

```
location: Array(3)
  0: {addressLine1: "", addressLine2: "", country: ""}
  1: {addressLine1: "1", addressLine2: "2", country: "Brazil"}
  2: {addressLine1: "X", addressLine2: "Y", country: "Portugal"}
```

How can I adapt my `onAddLocation` function to filter out the first *empty* entry, so only entries that have values are saved.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why have initial state?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question. I have the initial state for `name`, because the `handleChange` function overwrites the `""`. But for the `location` I am just pushing new entries to it, without overwriting the initial state. Are you saying I don't need an initial state for the location fields?

Comment: Yes, he is saying that you should keep the array empty, like this: `location: [ ], locationAdded: "" ...`

Comment: Oh I see! That makes sense, thank you both.

Comment: Have you tried using Formik instead of handling the form state itself? I think it will save you from a lot of headaches.

Comment: I haven't, but I have heard of it, and keep meaning to check it out - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and incorrectly formatted

Comment: Please explain how it is incomplete and incorrectly formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I would not have placeholder data in the set. If you can avoid it, then this might work.

```
const placeholderAddress = {
  addressLine1: "",
  addressLine2: "",
  country: "",
}

const location = this.state.location.length > 0 ? this.state.location : [placeholderAddress];

const yourData = {
  name: "",
  location: location,
  locationAdded: "",
}
```

Comment: You are just telling him how to sweep the problem under the rug

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it added the data to the state is because of spreading the data to the array state. My solution to the problem is to filter all the data that's not empty and add the new one.

Check the code below.

```
const onAddLocation = () => {
  const { addressLine1, addressLine2, country } = this.state;

  this.setState(oldState => ([
    ...oldState.filter(item => item.addressLine1 !== '' && item.addressLine2 && item.country),
    {
      addressLine1,
      addressLine2,
      country
    }
  ]));
}
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: If he removes what you stated, then he can't add anything more than 1 location

Comment: Thanks for the response, but yes, I need that so I can add multiple values to the state. For fields that don't require multiple values (such as name) I don't call the `onAddLocation` function, just `handleChange`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<Form>
  <Label>Country<Label>
    <Form.Control 
     name="country" 
     value={this.state.name}
     onChange={this.handleChange} />
</Form>
```

You were passing as `value` a prop from an object within an array. I assume that the `name=""` in your state is to handle your input text changes. If this isn't doesn't directly solve your issue it moves towards the right direction.

Comment: This is vague and not helping answering the question.